# Accuracy of stable (not backward stable) numerical algorithm

Tags: stability, numerical-methods

I understand the definition of accuracy for a backward stable numerical algorithm, which shows how such a quantity depends both on machine-epsilon and on the condition number of the problem under examination.

However, many numerical algorithms used in practice are only stable, not backward stable. Which is a proper definition of accuracy for this class of algorithms? I feel it should still involve the notions of condition number and machine-epsilon, but I'm looking for formal definition / derivation